# Bootstrap: different content for XS screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a PHP/MYSQL website.
For most of the pages the responsive design with Bootstrap is fine.
But for a few pages not only the columns have to rearrange for **xs screen sizes**, but the content of the divisions change also. Below is an example of a page which is quite different on for the **xs version**.

[image]

What I did is simple: I used `hidden-xs` to hide the layout on large screens and `visible-xs` to show the layout on small screens. So I guess the page needs twice the resources to load which is not highly optimal.

Is there a more optimized way to deal with this issue of different style and content for different screen sizes when it only concerns a few pages? (if all the pages where very different I guess the best solution would be to create a mobile version on a sub-domain).

Comment: Bootstrap calls itself mobile first. What happens when you think the other way around? Create it for mobile first, then give the parts the values needed for bigger screens.

Comment: Could the person who voted down my question explain why he did so, so that I can maybe make it clearer?

Answer (score 0):

I am familiar with a method although I personally never got the chance to use it. You can create stylesheets for different screen sizes.

```
<head>
      <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 257px)' href='your-css.css'/>
</head>
```

Comment: Yes I am using this technique. But in some cases not only the style changes but also some divisions. That's why it is easy to just hide a div and make visible a new one. What I am not sure is: are all the divisions loaded in that case or only the visible ones, i.e is the page 2 times more heavy.